# How to implement Copy trait for Custom struct?

Tags: struct, rust, traits

I have my custom struct - Transaction, I would like I could copy it.

> This fails because Vec does not implement Copy for any T. [E0204](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/error-index.html#E0204)

How to implement copy to Vec and my struct. I am asking for an example.

[Playground](https://gist.github.com/72fd4cb07634e186027cd4329e1e766b)

```
#[derive(PartialOrd, Eq, Hash)]
struct Transaction {
    transaction_id: Vec<u8>,
    proto_id: Vec<u8>,
    len_field: Vec<u8>,
    unit_id: u8,
    func_nr: u8,
    count_bytes: u8,
}

impl Copy for Transaction { }

impl Clone for Transaction {
    fn clone(&self) -> Transaction {
        *self
    }
}

impl PartialEq for Transaction {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        self.unit_id == other.unit_id
            && self.func_nr == other.func_nr
            && self.count_bytes == other.count_bytes
    }
}

fn main() 
{
}
```

Comment: Do you *really* want to copy three vectors every time you use the transaction struct, every time you pass it to a function ? What's your real problem ? Copying a struct doesn't involve using the `Copy` trait.

Comment: Do you mean `Copy` or `Clone`, in rust it is somewhat different.

Comment: @edwardw I don't think this is a duplicate because it's a XY question IMO.

Comment: @DenysSéguret the answer to that question also answered this one IMO.

Comment: The documentation shows that there is no implementation for the 'Copy' Vec <T> trait. I understand that this should be implemented.

Comment: Why do you think you need to implement the `Copy` trait ? It's not needed to copy values and you should *not* use it for big values like vectors.

Comment: Denys, I will use small vectors (2 elements).
I bypassed this problem - instead of Vec <u8> I used arrays. But I still don't have the answer. As it should be written using Vec <u8>.

Comment: @MichałHanusek: There is no way to implement Copy for your type. The Copy trait is for types that can be bitwise copied, and it requires that all members implement Copy. Vec does not implement Copy (because it cannot be bitwise copied), therefore your type cannot implement Copy. If you simply want to be able to duplicate an object, use Clone.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I'm solved this problem:
I used tables [u8; 2] instead of Vec .

But I still don't understand why you can't use vectors in a structure and copy it.

```
#[derive(PartialOrd, Eq, Copy, Clone, Hash)]
struct Transaction {
    transaction_id: [u8; 2],
    proto_id:  [u8; 2],
    len_field: [u8; 2],
    unit_id: u8,
    func_nr: u8,
    count_bytes: u8,
}

impl PartialEq for Transaction {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        self.unit_id == other.unit_id
            && self.func_nr == other.func_nr
            && self.count_bytes == other.count_bytes
    }
}
```

Comment: "But I still don't understand why you can't use vectors in a structure and copy it." just read the duplicate - -